# String Array to text document and read it

Tags: c#, arrays, console

I'm having issues with with making a program.
I need to make it so it checks whether a text file exists or not, if it exists it displays the contents, if not it prompts the user to enter 5 names, these names are stored into an array are then sent to the text document. I've already tried to do it but I'm getting an error.

Note:
I need to do the names in an array.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Array
{
    class Program
    {
        public static string line;
        public const string file = @"D:\information.txt";
        public static string names = @"D:\names.txt";
        public static StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(names);
        public static string[] namesArray = new string[4];

        public static bool checkFileExists(string names)    
        {
            bool b = false;
            if (File.Exists(names))
            {
                b = true;
            }
            return b;
        }

        static void reset() //void used to reset the program
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.Write("\nIf there is an error, press Enter to restart");
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White; //changes the text colour of the next line of code to white, better visuals
            Console.ReadLine(); //the readkey used to read for any keys being pressed for restarting
            Console.Clear(); //clears the console and resets it back to normal
        }

        static void toFile()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
            string[] namesArray = new string[5];
            Random RandString = new Random();

            StreamWriter info = new StreamWriter(file);

            for (int x = 0; x < namesArray.Length; x++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a name of class member: {0}", namesArray[x]);
                namesArray[x] = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            for (int x = 0; x < namesArray.Length; x++)
            {
                info.WriteLine("{0}", namesArray[x]);
            }
            info.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Class names to array";
                try
                {
                    if (checkFileExists(names))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("file exists, the contents of the file is: ");
                        while (myFile1.EndOfStream == false)
                        {
                            line = myFile1.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toFile();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
                }
        }
    }
```

The error I'm getting is **'The type initializer for 'Array.Program' threw an exception**' and it just closes down.

I've also been told by a friend that my code is really messy, I'm not sure what I need to do to make it better but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @cdhowie said, you will find the details in InnerException. I did notice that your code was a little bit strung out, and admittedly messy, so I decided to write a little sample that does what you want it to in way fewer lines. Many times when doing simple file operations, you can avoid using `StreamReader` or `StreamWriter` and instead just use the [File class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx).

Here is the code sample:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string file = @"D:\information.txt";
            if (File.Exists(file))
                foreach(var s in File.ReadAllLines(file))
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
            else
            {
                string[] src = new string[5];
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter 5 names:");
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    src[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                File.Create(file).Close();
                File.WriteAllLines(file, src)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the details of the "inner exception" in a debugger.  You should see that the problem is this line:

```
public static StreamReader myFile = new StreamReader(names);
```

This is the only line that could be causing this problem, and likely occurs because the filename contained by the `names` field doesn't exist, or you don't have access to it (permissions or sharing violation, for example).  Correct the problem indicated by the inner exception to make the exception stop happening.

Note that if you did this assignment in the `Main()` method that the real error would not be masked by the `TypeInitializationException`, which is thrown whenever a static constructor throws an exception.